# How to update list of dictionaries using another list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists as shown below. I want to update the new list using the old list. The criteria to update the new list are matching values for `name` in old list. What is the best way to do it?

**Input**

```
old_list = [{'age': 35, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 42, 'name': 'bob'}]

new_list = [{'name': 'peter'}, {'name': 'james'}, {'age': 50, 'name': 'bob'}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{'name': 'peter'}, {'age': 35, 'name': 'james'}, {'age': 42, 'name': 'bob'}]
```

**Edit: Adding my solution**

One solution that I know to solve this using multiple loops and if conditions. It is not the compete solution as I need to handle multiple scenarios like where key is not present etc.

```
for x in new_col_list:
    for y in old_col_list:
        if x['name'] == y['name']:
            x['age'] = y['age']
            continue

print new_col_list
```

Comment: do you want the age of 'bob' to stay at 42 or update to 50?

Comment: I want to take values from old list. So in this case, I want to update 50 to 42.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this? It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I tried to do it but the way I am thinking to solve involves multiple loops which involves a lengthy code. But I think there are better ways to solve this using Lambda/ in line functions but I am all new to programming and finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for your answer. I will try to use an understand the same. Regarding what you quote above. Yes, I have a total of six years of experience and building bi solutions but I always used SQL to do that. I am new to programming but not to IT. I can think of solving same problem in SQL update target table by joining the source table on name column. But in python, its different.

Comment: Fair enough. All the same, always post an attempted solution when you ask this sort of thing. It shows that you've at least spent the effort that you're demanding of others yourself on the problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. Point taken. Now onwards, I will add my attempt in every question that I ask. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180006/discussion-between-aashish-ola-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a structure that will allow you to do the lookup of items in one list from the other. A dictionary provides such a structure:

```
lookup = {x['name']: x for x in new_list}
lookup.update({x['name']: x for x in old_list})
```

You can then convert back to a list if you really want to:

```
result = list(lookup.values())
```

In Python 3.6+, the order of the values will be all the elements of the new list, followed by all the missing elements added from the old list in the order they were in the old list. For older versions of Python, the same can be achieved by `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
lookup = OrderedDict((x['name'], x) for x in new_list)
lookup.update((x['name'], x) for x in old_list)
```

Without the ordering, the result of `dict.values()` will be in arbitrary order, and may change between runs of the interpreter.

**Appendix**

Any time you see a dictionary comprehension, it is functionally equivalent to a `for` loop. Here is the "expanded" version of the first suggested code:

```
lookup = {}
for d in new_list:
    lookup[d['name']] = d
for d in old_list:
    lookup[d['name']] = d
```

Comment: Actually, coming from sql background and having very limited knowledge of programming (if else, loops etc), it is difficult to understand this type of syntax - {x['name']: x for x in new_list}

I see that the first line creates a dict using the new_list and second line updates this newly created dictionary using old one. At first go it looks very difficult to understand this syntax because I always try to think in terms of solving problem using loops, if else conditions.

Comment: That syntax is not necessary to solve the problem. It's a bit faster and cleaner than writing the full for loop though. It's doing it exactly the way you are thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks. I just overwritten the code that I wrote but let me write it and share it again. Somehow I feel that what I was doing is not a good way to solve this. I need 10 minutes to share my solution.

Comment: I added my code where I was trying to solve this. But there are multiple scenarios which I need to handle in that to make it full proof.